# Is there a global parameter that limits the number of variables handled by Simplify?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, assumptions

It seems that `Simplify` is unable to handle (at least some) expressions involving 22 or more variables. Consider the code snippet below:

```
X = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12};
Y = {y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9, y10, y11, y12};
$Assumptions = 
  Element[X, PositiveIntegers] && Element[Y, PositiveIntegers] && 
   And @@ Table[X[[i]] > Y[[i]], {i, 1, 12}];
```

Several simplifications all return `True` as expected:

```
In[4]:= Simplify[x1 > y1]
Out[4]= True

In[5]:= Simplify[x1 + x2 > y1 + y2]
Out[5]= True

In[6]:= Simplify[Total[X[[1 ;; 10]]] > Total[Y[[1 ;; 10]]]]
Out[6]= True

In[7]:= Simplify[Total[X] > Total[Y[[1 ;; 9]]]] (*21 variables*)
Out[7]= True
```

However, if I try to simplify an expression involving 22 or more variables, `Simplify` is unable to handle it:

```
In[8]:= Simplify[Total[X[[1 ;; 11]]] > Total[Y[[1 ;; 11]]]]
Out[8]= x1 + x10 + x11 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 > 
 y1 + y10 + y11 + y2 + y3 + y4 + y5 + y6 + y7 + y8 + y9
(*True expected*)

In[9]:= Simplify[Total[X] > Total[Y]]
Out[9]= x1 + x10 + x11 + x12 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 > 
 y1 + y10 + y11 + y12 + y2 + y3 + y4 + y5 + y6 + y7 + y8 + y9
(*True expected*)
```

I couldn't find any global option in the documentation that limits how many variables `Simplify` will handle.  Is there such a parameter that can be increased to deal with more variables?  Or is there some other way to handle this many variables?  (I also tried using `Refine` and `FullSimplify` with the same result).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"Is there a global parameter that limits the number of variables handled by Simplify?"*

Yes... System option `"SimplificationOptions"` gives a list of suboptions and their default settings.:

```
SystemOptions["Simplif*"]
{"SimplificationOptions" -> {"AssumptionsMaxExponent" -> 25, 
   "AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 4, 
   "AssumptionsMaxVariables" -> 21, "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> True, 
   "AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog" -> True, 
   "ConvertTrigsToRadicals" -> False, "FiniteSumMaxTerms" -> 30, 
   "FunctionExpandMaxSteps" -> 15, "ListableFirst" -> True, 
   "RestartELProver" -> False, "SimplifyMaxExponents" -> 100, 
   "SimplifyToPiecewise" -> True}}
```

Your examples hit the limit given by `"AssumptionsMaxVariables" -> 21`.

You can increase the limits using, for example,

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> "AssumptionsMaxVariables" -> 50]
```

***Note:***  In version 11.3, using `FullSimplify` (instead of `Simplify`) gives `True` for the last two examples without having to change the system options. `Simplify` does not return `True` even if we set a large value for the system option `"AssumptionsMaxVariables"`.